# player.update wont take key input and make character move pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame and this code I created by following a tutorial is not working. The white box i made on the screen should be moving with my arrow keys but its not. Does anyone know why? Also can someone explain what self means in the class and defs?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))



#Define a player object by extending pygame.sprite.Sprite
# The surface drawn on the screen is now an attribute of Player

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player,self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75,25))
        self.surf.fill((255,255,255))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0,-5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0,5)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5,0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5,0)
    


#Instantiate player        


pygame.init()

player = Player()


#keeps main loop running
running = True

#main loop
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #Did user hit a key?
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # Was it the escape key? if so, exit loop
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False


        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False



    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    player.update(pressed_keys)

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    screen.blit(player.surf,(SCREEN_WIDTH/2,SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

I tried to make the block move by clicking the arrow keys.

Comment: `by clicking the arrow keys` Keys are _pressed_, not _clicked_.  "click" means something with the mouse buttons.

Comment: So did you actually _click_ an arrow key?  Or did you _press_ it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always draw the player in the center of the screen:

> ```py
> screen.blit(player.surf,(SCREEN_WIDTH/2,SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
> ```

You have to draw the player at `player.rect`:

```py
screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
```

---

However, since you use `pygame.sprite.Sprite` you should also use `pygame.sprite.Group` and you should limit the frames per second with `pygame.time.Clock.tick`:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Player()
spriteGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
spriteGroup.add(player)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    spriteGroup.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```